# How to configure inbound route from kubernetes load balancer to backend node pool on azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, routes, load-balancing, nat

I am having some problems connecting to my new kubernetes cluster. I want to connect from an external dns using port 80 to port 3000 on my cluster which should be running a docker container that is hosting an express app that is listening on this port.

I have configured a kubernetes service which is running. The docker container spins up locally fine and I can reach it on localhost:3000

I have tried configuring a NAT inbound rule by my kubernetes backend pool does not appear as a target vm.

I have configured a load balancer rule with 80 on the outside edge routing to 3000 on the backend pool but I still cannot reach it.

I also cannot see under the covers to find out how the route is configured or how to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please show the yaml you have used.

Comment: Which service do you use? Azure Kubernetes Service or aks-engine or you just configure the Kubernetes cluster in the VM yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Without showing us the manifest files you used to create your resources, it's hard to pinpoint the problem.  You may have simply forgot to specify a target port on the load balancer definition.

In this example, the load balancer listens on port 80 and redirect the traffic on port 8080 to the pod(s) using the app:hpa-pod selector.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hpa-lb
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: hpa-pod
```

Pod listening on port 8080

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hpa-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hpa-pod
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hpa-pod
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: hpa-pod
        image: k8sacademy/kuard:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
```

Comment: Rather interestingly this manifest file seems to be abstracted away not only during the portal process for creating a kubernetes service, but also after the service is created there is no "view manifest file" option to be seen. Is there a portal based walkthrough of how to set up a kubernetes service with port forwarding, effectively a screen by screen to presumably render some soft of manifest such as the one you have kindly demonstrated above?

Comment: If you're looking for a Web UI, try launching the Kubernetes Dashboard (setup instructions in the Azure documentation).  You can then see the deployed objects and look at the manifest files.